# Can anyone identify this old German bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I found this old bike, it comes from Berlin, the brand is ACTIVE, but can’t find anything online about the brand. Is this worth putting 500 euro in to restore? Is the bike rare?

[image: Photograph of a blue-and-white painted step-through cruiser-style bike lying on the grass]

Comment: Why exactly 500€? This bike was worth considerably less when it was new.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about this particular brand, but I can tell that this is a typical 1980s six-speed bike (the handlebar grips look like a later addition, maybe 90s). In my elementary school half of the students had a bike like this from one or other local brand. They cost less than 500€ adjusted for inflation when new, and before the current shortage 500€ could buy a much better new bike. If this bike does not have documented interesting history, it does not have much monetary value.

On the other hand, it looks like it's in decent shape, so it could be usable right now, or be fixed to usable condition with some adjustment, lubrication and new tires and brake pads.